# Use DiffUtil when data doesn't start at index 0

Tags: android, androidx, android-diffutils

My items in my RecyclerView are structured as follows:

```
Index | Item
0.      Header Item
1.      0. Data 
2.      1. Data
3.      2. Data
4.      3. Data
[....]
```

My database automatically dispatches updates to the RecyclerView.
When using DiffUtil and i remove the item at index 3. in my database item at index 2. is being removed by DiffUitl Dispatcher. I think this is due DiffUtil dispatcher doesn't know that my items are "offset" by one index. How can i fix this?

Comment: You should not rely on your database rows and `RecyclerView` positions being the same. I suggest keeping a database id for each `Data` item and deleting based on that id instead of the `RecyclerView` adapter position.

Comment: The data is deleted based on an id. My problem is that diffutil doesn't know that i have added a header item that moves all data items down by one

Comment: Well, why not? You can use DiffUtil on multiple item types and diff based on both item type and content.

Comment: Thats a good idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use DiffUtil.DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(ListUpdateCallback), implement custom ListUpdateCallback

Example:

```
private class CustomListUpdateCallback(val adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>) : ListUpdateCallback {
    override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int, payload: Any?) {
        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position + 1, count, payload)
    }

    override fun onMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
        adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition + 1, toPosition + 1)
    }

    override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
        adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position + 1, count)
    }

    override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {
        adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position + 1, count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example to your answer?

Comment: I've added example

Comment: This can cause the initial items after the header to move up & get removed from the list, use `return` if the position is 0 instead.